# Como faço para escolher o local de download de um relatório feito em jasper?

Tags: ireport, relatório, download, jasper

Então, criei uma aplicação que gera um arquivo ODT... no código estou especificando exatamente o local onde o mesmo deverá ficar salvo, que é em 'c:/teste/sample_report.odt'... coloquei este nome para teste... o problema é que o arquivo sempre ficará salvo nesta pasta... não quero isso, quando estamos navegando na internet e baixamos um arquivo e clicamos nele, usando o chrome por exemplo ele já baixa para a pasta 'downloads', com o firefox ou IE aparece uma janela para escolher o local onde será salvo, é isso que quero... o problema da forma que fiz é que a pessoa precisa ter a pasta 'teste' em 'c:'... não quero isso, quero que ao clicar funcione como qualquer outro download feito na net... segue o meu código:
.

```
   try {
    URL arquivo = getClass().getResource(/reports/term.jasper);
    JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(arquivo);

   //Aqui é gerado o DTO que será enviado para o IReport
    ArrayList<MinutoTRDto> dataList = getDataBeanList(licitacao);
    JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dataList);

    Map<String, Object> parameters = getParametros();            
    JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, beanColDataSource);

    JROdtExporter exporterOdt = new JROdtExporter();
    exporterOdt.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(print));





    // AQUI ESTA O GRANDE PROBLEMA!
    exporterOdt.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput("C://teste//sample_report.odt"));
    exporterOdt.exportReport();

} catch (JRException jre) {
    jre.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Se você quer que o usuário escolha o local que irá salvar, basta usar JFileChooser, ai ele escolhe onde quer salvar e você passa o caminho onde será salvo...

Comment: Mas o JFileChooser não irá funcionar para este caso... o relatório é gerado automaticamente, clico no botão e gero o relatório e o mesmo já tem que ser baixado... só não quero obrigar a pessoa a ter na unidade C: uma pasta chamada teste... o problema esta nesta linha...   --> --> exporterOdt.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput("C://teste//sample_report.odt"));... ... este "C://teste//sample...." cria o arquivo nesta pasta... existem outros relatórios sendo salvos na aplicação que Web, só que usando outra biblioteca, neste caso estou gerando ODT...

Comment: Da forma que estamos usando na aplicação para PDF (que também é gerado automaticamente) ao clicar no botão de relatório o arquivo é gerado e já salvo na pasta download, e se eu ficar clicando no mesmo botão irá gerar varios arquivos ... tipo "relatorio.pdf", relatório(1).pdf, relatório(2).pdf... e assim até o último.